# Unable to connect Angular to Nodejs database (deployment using cPanel)

Tags: node.js, angular

I am deploying a website composed of front (angular) and back (nodejs) using cPanel, I have a GET connection error http://localhost:3000/api/products/net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED that I do not have not been able to resolve for some time. Do you have any ideas ?
Here is my code

Back:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'maydbname'
});


// Connection to port
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());

//Select all products
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM products'
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
    })
})
```

Front :
environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xxxx"
  }
};
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xxx"
  }
};
```

Service:

```
  private url = environment.serverURL;

  getAllProducts(): Observable<ProductModelServer[]> {
    return this.http.get<ProductModelServer[]>(this.url + 'products/');
  }
```

There is error message :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHcvq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation I found that it was necessary to replace in the prod environment file:
serverURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
by
serverURL: 'https://WebsiteAddress/api/',